# How to configure Rails to create the session cookie only when needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, cookies, devise

I have a Rails 4.2 application with Devise and I would like it to create the session cookie (_myapp_session) ONLY IF really is needed (ie. if I do login or write something to session manually).

Actually It is creating the session cookie by simply accessing a simple page, without nothing there.

Any suggestion how to accomplish? Thank you in advance.

Best,
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout `store?` method of devise strategies module.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FStrategies%2FAuthenticatable:store%3F

`def store?
  super && !mapping.to.skip_session_storage.include?(authentication_type)
end`

You can override this method if you want to skip session storage. By default, its `true`

Hope that helps.